# How to merge data from two paginated source APIs and expose it on another Paginated Restful API?

Tags: api, azure-logic-apps, pagination

Say I have API-A that sends information on type of apples -  100 types of apples in DB and API exposes only 10 at a time. Total records will be shown during first call as 100.
and Say I have API-O that sends information on type of Oranges -  100 types of oranges in DB and API exposes only 10 at a time. Total records will be shown during first call as 100.

How Do I write API-Fruits and paginate it at 10, so I can take data from both API-A and API-O , merge and expose on API-Fruits?

The only way I can think of is call API-A and API-O iteratively, capture all entries in an array from both APIs, and once I have information on all 100 apples and 100 oranges, then paginate it in response.

Any better way of dealing with this problem?

Note that I wouldn't know how may apple and orange types are present at the time of design and they wont be 100 all the time.